# Access data returned from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am looking to access the actual value returned from the server.`getRowData` returns the value after unformat applied to the value. This results in loss of information.

For instance, if a double value is rounded to two decimal places and if I want to populate the form for edit with the original value returned from the server with 6 decimals, how can I get the value returned.

for eg:

Value returned from server : 12.345678

formatter option for column : `formatter: 'number', formatoptions: {thousandsSeparator: ",", decimalPlaces: 2}`

Value displayed in grid : 12.35

How do I retrieve the value 12.345678 returned from the server. `getRowData` returns 12.35

I am using json data returned from the server. Using firebug I have confirmed that the server returns all 6 decimal places. Its only when retrieving the value from selected row that the decimal places are truncated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unformat` to get the original value, for methods such as `getRowData`. There is more information in the [Custom Formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) section of the jqGrid wiki. In particular they include the following example:

```
<script>
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({
...
   colModel: [ 
      ... 
      {name:'price', index:'price', width:60, align:"center", editable: true, formatter:currencyFmatter},
      ...
   ]
...
});

function currencyFmatter (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
   // do something here
   return new_format_value
}
</script>
```

So in your unformatter you should be able to just take the raw value (with more than 2 decimal places) and return it.

Comment: The `unformat` still does not return the original data, especially with the fractions. This does not seem to be possible at the moment so I have resorted to pulling the necessary information from the server. I have also opened a feature request in the support forum.